# SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataGridView.DataSource) duplicates all rows

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sqldataadapter

Simple question:

When I call `SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataGridView.DataSource)` the second time after initially creating first Data it does not update the contained rows. It simply adds all rows returned by the select command to my DataGridView.

If I call it a third, fourth (so on) it will also just add the returned rows.

Am I understanding the .Fill(DataTable) function wrong? How do I update the already existing DataTable correctly? Which line of code is responsible for that?

---

**Turns out it has to be a code problem;**

```
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    Dim sql = "select * from myTable"
    oDtSource = New DataTable
    oAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
    oCon = sqlCon("serverName\Instance", "myDataBase") ' Returns a SqlConnection
    oCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, oCon)
    oCon.Open()

    oDtSource.Clear()

    oAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    oAdapter.SelectCommand = oCmd
    oAdapter.Fill(oDtSource)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = oDtSource
```

For refreshing I use `oAdapter.Fill(oDtSource)` 
The PrimaryKey is set in the database

Comment: Please show how you set up the DataAdapter (I assume you are trying to refresh the data, otherwise just use a New datatable or clear the rows).  No idea why the DV other than may lack of code - it is a decent question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Tim Schmelter got me to the correct path. WorkTime is over now so I'll have to check that tomorrow. Thanks again @Plutonix for bringing me to that path of trying the actual .Fill method instead of creating new tables over and over again.

Comment: Code was posted above.

Comment: I would load the schema *and* define the `PrimaryKey` on the DataTable.  It works well to refresh rows, though there can be a trick to refreshing when you have added rows

Comment: What would the command for that look like and at which line should it be posted? I tried using `oDtSource.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {oDtSource.Columns("myPrimaryKey")}` after the first call of `oAdapter.Fill(oDtSource)` but it didnt seem to work for me. It still ended up in rows beeing added instead of updated .

Comment: can you clarify `didnt seem to work for me`

Answer (score 5):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx):

> You can use the `Fill` method multiple times on the same `DataTable`. If a
>   primary key exists, incoming rows are merged with matching rows that
>   already exist. If no primary key exists, **incoming rows are appended to
>   the DataTable**.

So either define a primary key or clear the table first.

```
Dim table = CType(DataGridView.DataSource, DataTable)
table.Clear()
' fill  ...
```

To define primary key(s) manually read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z24kefs8(v=vs.110).aspx). To let it create automatically if they are defined in the database you need to set the `MissingSchemaAction` to `AddWithKey`:

```
' ...
dataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction =  MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
' fill ...
```

Comment: Thats good stuff, shouldve looked to MSDN right away. My bad. Cant find the command to set the primary key. Could you help me with that as well?

Comment: @Luke: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z24kefs8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm still missing something. I'll check that tomorrow. Huge thanks already. Gotta leave work now otherwise I'll be stuck here til tomorrow ;-)

Comment: Okay, turns out I'm checking it today. This one kinda got me into it. I want to solve that. Could you take a look at the code I posted?

Comment: @luke: sorry, but now my work is over. I will have a look tomorrow if you're still struggling with it

Comment: @TimSchmelter, thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

The `edit` code doesnt show the `PrimaryKey` being defined for the `DataTable`.  This will configure the `DataAdapter` to perform updates and enabled refreshing the `DataTable`.  The code uses `MySQL` but the Provider objects all work the same in this regard:

```
' persistant form level vars
Private daSample As MySqlDataAdapter
Private dtSample As DataTable
...
```

Elsewhere:

```
' there are caveats with WHERE clauses
Dim sql = "SELECT Id, Name, Country, Animal FROM SAMPLE WHERE Color = 'onyx'"

' using the ctor overload, no need for a DbCommand or Connection object
daSample = New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, MySQLConnStr)

' initialize the CommandBuilder, get other commands 
Dim cbSample = New MySqlCommandBuilder(daSample)

daSample.UpdateCommand = cbSample.GetUpdateCommand
daSample.InsertCommand = cbSample.GetInsertCommand
daSample.DeleteCommand = cbSample.GetDeleteCommand

dtSample = New DataTable()
daSample.FillSchema(dtSample, SchemaType.Source)
dtSample.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dtSample.Columns("id")}

daSample.Fill(dtSample)

dgv1.DataSource = dtSample
```

To pick up changes made to the db from other client apps:

```
daSample.Fill(dtSample)
```

Initial display:

[image]

After I change a row to "onyx" from a UI browser and `Update` the changed row shows up:

[image]

`WHERE` clauses can be a bit of an issue.  Since it restricts the subset of data pulled back, `Update` is only going to compare rows in the *new* result set.  So, if I change an `onlyx` row to "blue" it wont be removed.

One solution is to use `.DefaultView.RowFilter` on the table, but that can slow things down since it requires returning all rows to the client to be filtered there.  Its not perfect.

Comment: I removed the commandbuilder part because it gave me an exception. I pretty much copy pasted the rest of the code because i didn't find the missing line for me. It is working  (no duplicated rows, new rows are displayed after refreshing with .Fill) with just one little problem; Calling .Fill(Table) to refresh the data takes 30 seconds when i have about 1000 entrys. Is it supposed to take that much time?

Comment: I would not hazard a guess why it is slow from so little info.  It is easy to time almost anything using the `StopWatch` class.  The DGV is only going to redraw the rows that are showing, so it almost certainly is not to blame.