# SQLiteDataAdapter Fill() method adding new rows rather than refreshing them

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable, dataadapter

I have a `SQLiteDataAdapter` object which fills a `DataTable`. During initialization, I call the adapter's `Fill()` method on the table. This is bound to a `DataGrid`, and later I run an operation on the database not through the `DataGrid`, and I need to force a refresh to the table.

The System.Data.SQLite docs describe `SQLiteDataAdapter`'s `Fill()` method as:

> Overloaded. Adds or refreshes rows in the `DataSet` to match those in the data source using the `DataSet` and `DataTable` names.

However, merely calling the adapter's `Fill()` method again on the table adds a second copy of every row. To get the behavior I'm expecting, which is to refresh the rows, I've resorted to calling the table's `Clear()` method followed by `Fill()`, and now I'm getting the behavior I expected.

Do I really need to call `Clear()` on the table before `Fill()`, or is there an option or something else I'm missing to attain the desired refresh behavior?

Comment: [Do you have a primary key defined in the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636620/sqldataadapter-filldatagridview-datasource-duplicates-all-rows) ?

Comment: The Refresh ability works great.  Duplicating rows can happen for a number of reasons, one being that the row states get lost.  We cant see any of the code, so anything more would be a guess.

Comment: @Crowcoder setting a primary key did it. Thank you.