# Double data entry in C# UI and MYSQL DB

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I'm create a new signup page successfully. whenever I enter a username and password  and hit a submit button it save's the credentials but the problem here is two times entered that data.

```
private void sbmtbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (usrnmtxtbx.Text != "")
        {
            if (pswdtxtbx.Text != "")
            {
                if (cnfrmtxtbx.Text != "")
                {
                    if (pswdtxtbx.Text == cnfrmtxtbx.Text)
                    {
                        MySqlConnection Con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                        MySqlCommand Cmd;
                        Con.Open();
                        try
                        {
                            Cmd = Con.CreateCommand();
                            Cmd.CommandText = "INSERT IGNORE INTO signup(username, password,confirm) VALUES(@username,@password,@confirm)";
                            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usrnmtxtbx.Text;
                            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pswdtxtbx.Text;
                            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@confirm", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cnfrmtxtbx.Text;

                            DataTable table = new DataTable();
                            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                            adapter.SelectCommand = Cmd;
                            adapter.Fill(table);
                            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            MessageBox.Show("Your Account resgistred Successfully", "information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            Con.Close();
                        }
                    }
               } 
          }
     }
 }
```

**OutPut :**

idsignup   username  password confirm

1           hello      123      123

2           hello      123      123

Comment: This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636620/sqldataadapter-filldatagridview-datasource-duplicates-all-rows

Comment: either make the username unique or check wether it already exists befor you add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` inserts the row into the table; that's all the code you need. The `DataTable` and `MySqlDataAdapter` are completely unnecessary (and duplicating the data); you should delete that code.

Also, storing users' passwords directly in your database is an extremely bad idea and should be completely avoided. Please research "password hashing" and "salting" and store the passwords securely. Ideally you could use an existing ASP.NET identity system and avoid building your own.

Some existing answers:

- [How to hash a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402129/23633)
- [How to hash users' passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54689642/23633)

Comment: Also consider usage of Using keyoword since most of the objects are disposables,